# Gen code without runtime checks in VC++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, compiler-construction

How do I generate pure code (without runtime checks) in VC++ 2010 Express ? For example I  removed  Buffer Security Check ( set compile opt /GS-),  but in my code I again saw these  calls

```
call __security_init_cookie
...
call _RTC_CheckEsp
...
call _RTC_CheckEsp
...
```

How do I remove these calls?

Comment: For example without  _RTC_CheckEsp and __security_init_cookie calls. This is not my code

Comment: See [naked modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5w10wxs(v=VS.100).aspx). This may help you; however, you may need to do some 'clean-up' work.

Comment: Are these checks slowing down your code or causing any problems? Are you just a control freak?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MSVC docs indicate that `__security_init_cookie` is called by the CRT runtime for "code compiled with /GS (Buffer Security Check) **and** in code that uses exception handling" (emphasis added). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235362%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

I wouldn't be surprised if there's code in the runtime library itself that depends on the security cookie having been initialized, whether your code uses it or not (in other words, the runtime library code may have been compiled with /GS, and if so, it needs the cookie initialized whether or not your code does).

As for the `_RTC_CheckEsp` call - that should be controlled by the `/RTCs` or the `/RTC1` option.  Remove those options from your build and there should be no calls to `_RTC_CheckEsp`.

Comment: I.e. to get rid of it, you might need to get rid of the entire CRT. That's not as impossible as it sounds.

Comment: No, you don't need to get rid of the entire CRT. You just need to get rid of /RTCs or /RTC1 and /GS. Getting rid of the /RT switches disables the _RTC_CheckEsp calls. Getting rid of /GS gets rid of the __security_init_cookie calls.

The /RTCs checks can be particularly expensive if you are building with edit-and-continue - I've measured a 5x slowdown (in contrived examples, but still):

https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/visual-c-debug-buildsfast-checks-cause-5x-slowdowns/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you disable RTC it will only disable it from the code that you compile yourself. Anything that you take from static libraries (including crt static library) might have it's security_cookies already compiled into it's code.

Answer (score 3):

Disable /RTC compiler switch
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wtf2dfz.aspx